# When highlighting a block of code and right clicking, stop PhpStorm from focusing on included elements

Tags: phpstorm

Was hard to explain in the title, but what has been annoying me lately is when I highlight a block of code for example, with the intent to copy it via *right click* with my mouse, **PhpStorm** will commonly mess up the highlighted block if I happen to right click a *keyword* or something it recognizes within that block and then end up with that *keyword* just being highlighted.

**Example of intended highlight:**

[image]

**Now, if I right click for example `\Exception` in this block I end up with this:**

[image]

It doesn't happen 100% of the time, but enough to become very annoying.

Is there a way to stop this behaviour when I right click when I have a block selected and since I have the whole block selected I obviously am not interested in that particular case of `\Exception` even though I happened to right click on it.

Btw, I am using **PhpStorm 2016.2**.

**Edit:** Ok, I noticed it doesn't even matter if you right click on a *keyword*; I right clicked in blank space and I ended up with that particular line highlighted this time instead of the whole block I selected.

Comment: Tested decsribed issue, dozen of times, just now and working fine (on Windows, PhpStorm installed locally). AFAIK there's no setting for "right-click" in PhpStorm. I guess there's some issue in your environment. What's your OS, virtualization maybe, some resident app maybe?

Comment: @HonzaRydrych I'm running on `Win 7 Pro 64-Bit`.

Comment: Exactly same version of PHPStorm and Win7 x64 on my computer too and no issue here. Did you check how some other app (Word, Libre Office Writer, Notepad, ...) behaves when you do the same - right click on selected block of text?

Comment: @HonzaRydrych No problems in notepad haha.

Comment: Ghost in your machine :-)  The only way I can achieve to "reselect" block of text under cursor (keyword or whatever else) is LEFT button doubleclick. Checked with mouse / touchpad and with holding CTRL, ALT or SHIFT as well. Correctly working notepad eliminates faulty hardware. Seem like I'm out of ideas...

Comment: @HonzaRydrych Hmmmmm, yeah, LEFT double click works for me too. Perhaps my mouse is acting up *shrug*